# How to specify the groovy file in a JMeter JSR223 preprocessor under jmeter-maven-plugin?

Tags: maven, groovy, jmeter, jmeter-maven-plugin

I have several JMeter jmx files. They each have an initial script written in groovy and I specify that using a JSR223 PreProcessor giving the file name as `src/test/jmeter/LoadScript.groovy`. There are no imports, at least none I've written, only standard apache libraries.

This works just fine in the GUI environment. All my tests work and they share the same `LoadScript.groovy` file.

When I try and run this under maven using `jmeter-maven-plugin` it breaks because it comes up with a crazy looking path for the groovy file. eg

```
/home/roger/myproject/target/f4e97418-cbab-4ac8-ac4b-3bfbd686279a/jmeter/bin/src/test/jmeter/LoadScript.groovy
```

where I was hoping it would use just cwd plus the file path I specified.

I added this to the `jmeter-maven-plugin` to define a property with my basedir

```
            <configuration>
                <propertiesSystem>
                    <jmeter-base>${basedir}</jmeter-base>
                </propertiesSystem>
            </configuration>
```

and changed all my references to the groovy file to include `${jmeter-base}/` on the front. But still I get file not found references and now the path is:

```
/home/roger/myproject/datamanager-service/target/b9c995e2-699d-4d56-923b-a99afb566cfc/jmeter/bin/${jmeter-base}/src/test/jmeter/LoadScript.groovy
```

If this had worked it would have been a poor solution though because it would not allow the tests to be run under the GUI.

I would try having maven copy the files to the directory in the error message but the UUID in it is dynamically generated so that isn't possible as far as I can see.

There must be an easy way to do this. Anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 2):

JMeter Maven Plugin:

1. [Copies the contents](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Basic-Configuration#basic-configuration) of `src/test/jmeter` folder to `target/jmeter/testFiles`
2. Sets the [baseDir of the FileServer](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/services/FileServer.html#setBasedir-java.lang.String-) to that folder

So if you want to use relative paths - **the paths need to be relative to this folder.**

The easiest and the most flexible way would be using the following [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy) in the "File Name" field of your JSR223 Test Element:

```
${__groovy(org.apache.jmeter.services.FileServer.getFileServer().getBaseDir(),)}/LoadScript.groovy
```

[image]

and it will be resolved in all cases:

- running JMeter via maven as `maven verify`
- [running JMeter GUI via maven](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin/wiki/Basic-Configuration#running-the-jmeter-gui) as `mvn jmeter:configure jmeter:gui`
- running JMeter GUI from shell script or desktop shortcut and opening the .jmx script by browsing to it

More information: [How to Use the JMeter Maven Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-maven-plugin)